# What Java tools are available that'll report methods being used?

Tags: java

We're trying to move our very large codebase from Guava 11 to Guava 14 and would like to catch uses of removed or deprecated APIs. What (static analysis) Java tools are available that'll report methods being used?

Comment: How about the compiler which will pick up removed APIs (since it would generate a compiler error!) and deprecated API's through compiler warnings (you may need to tweak the compiler settings for this)?

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions; edit your original question instead.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Chris Knight, just compile your codebase against Guava 14.  The compiler will fail on deleted methods, and warn you about deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think this question violates SO's guidelines...

We use Sonar for static analysis of our applications: http://www.sonarsource.org/ .  Im not sure, but it may flag usage of depreciated APIs.  Of course a regular compile will catch the usage of removed APIs.